# SOLR search issue in wild character

Tags: search, solr

I have a search query in SOLR with wild char . My need is I need to set the character length. Is it possible in SOLR ?.

For Eg

status:(d*mo) -  I need to get only a word with 4 character, ie one character should be replaced in second position

Please help

Thanks

---

Great ! One more doubt. Do we need to put back slash before "?" ? ie does d\?mo is needed ? Also in SOLR whether single slash is supporting ? For Eg : Can I check the word "jack's" ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two forms of wildcard character:

- `asterisk ("*")` which will match zero or more arbitrary characters and
- `question mark ("?")` which will match exactly one arbitrary character.

If you want to check for single arbitary character you should use `?`

So `d?mo` would match words with 4 characters with second character being the variable part.

For Detailed information refer to [Wildcard Queries](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/lweug/Wildcard+Queries)

Comment: Great ! One more doubt. Do we need to put back slash before "?" ?  ie does d\?mo is needed ?   Also in SOLR whether single slash is supporting ? For Eg : Can I check the word "jack's"  ?

Comment: you may need to escape when using the special query parameters. I didn't get the jack's question ?

Comment: okay. my question is how i search Apostrophes? When I tried , its not working , is it possible in SOLR? For eg : Does the word jack's is searchable, if yes how?

Comment: it depends what field type you are using and how the field is being tokenied and analysed. It does work in SOLR.

Comment: Okay , can you show me a sample code , I am using field type as text